# Github shows name instead of a linked username in commits

Tags: github

I just helped a friend to set up a Github account to collaborate on my project. His commits come through, but for some reason on the "Source" page of my repository next to his commit is only his name and not his username (with a link).

It seems strange, since Github obviously recognizes him (I added him to the list of collaborators etc.

Seems like a stupid question, but Google couldn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Does your friend have the e-mail address he is using for his commits correctly set up as an alias in GitHub? Otherwise, how is GitHub to know who he is? Git itself only records the full name and the e-mail address and obviously not the GitHub username, since you can use Git perfectly fine without GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it seems to me that using that logic (StackOverflow is not the [whatever] support forum), 99% of StackOverflow would be gone.

Comment: For people like me wondering why the comment has more upvotes than the answer - The answer originally contained this line - "Please note that StackOverflow is not the GitHub support forum. There are better places for questions like this, like, say, the GitHub support forum."

Answer (score 10):

Run this in Terminal:

```
  git config --global user.name "your-github-username"
  git config --global user.email "your-github-email"
```

Comment: Please ignore this. You should never change your Git settings just because of where you happen to host your repository today. What happens if you decide tomorrow to host your repository on Gitorious or Assembla or Repo.Or.Cz or Codaset? Or you want to host it on multiple websites, for safety and redundancy? Instead of changing your Git settings to play nice with GitHub, you should change your GitHub settings to play nice with your Git settings.

Comment: Is the username/email attached to your commits going to be dramatically different if you're using different hosting providers?

Comment: The username and e-mail address attached to a Git commit is exactly what you tell Git to.

Comment: Right, I'm just suggesting that there's nothing wrong with putting your name and email address in your global Git config, if that's what you typically use to "sign" your commits.

Comment: You should do the above, but you shouldn't do the `--global` flag. That way it's repo specific.

Comment: Additionally, you can add more than one email to your github username under settings. Not sure if it retroactively updates old commits but your new ones definitely get associated to your github username.

Comment: user.name is the username? If yes, why do people type their names? Even the documentation says the same.

Answer (score 9):

Add the email used in the git commits to github via Account Settings: [Email Settings](https://github.com/settings/emails)

Answer (score 0):

Just ask your friend to add email that he use in local git commits to his GitHub account emails list as stated in [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the [GitHub article](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git):

`$ git config --global user.name "example"`

`$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Comment: this is redundant and literally a copy of @Shaun's bad answer.