# Can I associate a GitHub user with his commits by name only, BitBucket-style?

Tags: github

I've seen [Github shows name instead of a linked username in commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746562/github-shows-name-instead-of-a-linked-username-in-commits) and I realise that the right thing to do is to link by email. However, I already have a repository with a whole bunch of commits whose email is "none@none".

On BitBucket, I can specify a per-project mapping of committer name to BitBucket account, and this has worked well enough. Is there anything like this on GitHub?

If not, what other options are there, short of leaving the commits unlinked and rewriting the entire history?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.mailmap` file in your repo, for mail aliased (as stated in "[“Alias” git authors/committers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664324/6309)")

You also can add another email in your [Email setting account](https://github.com/settings/emails).

But both solutions don't scale well when *several* authors use the same `none@none` email.